# How to solve the issue with invalid value with json

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to receive some data from a json, I am using sequelize for my data the problem is when I send a post request the console give me the error:

```
Error: Invalid value { username: 'phernandez' }
    at Object.escape (C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\buildingapp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sql-string.js:65:11)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.escape (C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\buildingapp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:963:22)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator._whereParseSingleValueObject (C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\buildingapp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2420:41)
```

I already change the different parameters in postman sending for a different type, because _I was thinking I was sending a bad post request, sending by postman with x-form-www-urlencoded and then with body again

```
 //this is the file app.js
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
   app.use(bodyParser.json());

//and the routes 

router.post('/',(req,res)=> {
    var usuario=req.body;
    console.log(usuario);
    Usuario.findOne({
        where: {username:usuario},
        attributes:['username','password','niv_adm']
    })
    .then(usuario => {
        console.log(usuario);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

});
```

My expectations is receive this good and then make the consult in the data base I am using  and return the data I need

Comment: which line of the code you posted triggers the error?

Comment: I think I am calling in the bad way the bodyparser library, or I should called in my routes field, I don't know

Comment: could be the mapping because I am not making any reference in the model what parameter of my model I am using, anyway, thank you for your help, I already solve the problem

Comment: `where: req.body` would also have unwrapped it... but referring to fields is more readable. besides, programming in English would eliminate the requirement to mess around with translations, which refer to exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This still could be simplified alike that (because using two languages does not make anything easier):

```
router.post('/',(req,res)=> {
    Usuario.findOne({
        where: {username: req.body.username},
        attributes:['username','password','niv_adm']
    })
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I already solve the issue, I just need to pass the parameter of model you are using, like this, in the model section, thank you so much for the help

```
 var usuario=req.body.username;
```